# ListView Update doesn't update value

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am displayzing data in the list view and on selected item I am displaying pop up when the user can update the value

Now when I click on one field and edit it when I go back to the original page the value stay the same as it was before update. I have set the properties to the same model data and in the property Field Value when I debug I get stopped but the value doesn't change . Can you please help

```
ListView 
 <ListView BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" x:Name="list"  
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Results, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
                                   <!--Data-->
                                       <Label  Padding="10,4,0,4" Text ="{Binding FieldDescriptor}" Style="{StaticResource SubLabelBlackStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"      />
                                       <Label Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource SubLabelBlackStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  >
                                         
                                       </Label>
                                      
                          
                                  </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

PopUP

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1"  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SeparatorLineColor}"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                   <Entry  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SeparatorLineColor}"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="150"
                    Placeholder="{Binding FieldValue}"
                    Text="{Binding FieldValue}"
                Style="{StaticResource SubLabelBlackStyle}"
                    ReturnType="Next">
                 </Entry>
                </Grid>
      </Grid>

 public EditPopUp(DocumentData param, ResultPageViewModel model, int index)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new EditPopUpViewModel(param, model, index);
          
        }

public async Task UpdateValue(DocumentData selectedItem, int index)
        {
            Results.Insert(index, selectedItem);
        }

        private void OnItemSelected(DocumentData selectedItem)
        {
            var index = Results.IndexOf(selectedItem);
            Results.Remove(selectedItem);
            Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new EditPopUp(selectedItem, this, index));
        }
```

And my POP UP class

```
 public class EditPopUpViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
     
        private DocumentData _fieldValue;
        private string _fieldValueString;
        private string _fieldDescriptor;
        private int _num;
    
        public Command CancelPopUpCommand { get; }
        public Command ConfirmPopUpCommand { get; }

        public DocumentData FieldValue
        { get
            { return _fieldValue; }

            set
            {
                if (_fieldValue != value)
                { _fieldValue = value;
                    
               OnPropertyChanged("FieldValue"); }
            }
        }

        public string FieldValueString
        {
            set
            {
                _fieldValueString = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FieldValue));
            }
            get { return _fieldValueString; }
        }

        public string FieldDescriptor
        {
            set
            {
                _fieldDescriptor = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FieldDescriptor));
            }
            get { return _fieldDescriptor; }
        }

        public int Num
        {
            set
            {
                _num = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FieldValue));
            }
            get { return _num; }
        }

        public void Load(DocumentData param, int index)
        {
            FieldValue = param;
            FieldValueString = param.FieldValue;
            FieldDescriptor = param.FieldDescriptor;
            Num = index;
        }

        public EditPopUpViewModel(DocumentData param, ResultPageViewModel model, int index)
        {
           
            Load(param, index);

            ConfirmPopUpCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteConfirmPopUpCommand(model));
            CancelPopUpCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteCancelPopUpCommand());
        }

        private async Task ExecuteCancelPopUpCommand()
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
        }

        private async Task ExecuteConfirmPopUpCommand(ResultPageViewModel model)
        {
             model.UpdateValue(FieldValue, Num);
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
        }
```

Comment: The code is updated is not the same